# TypeScript - calling an API endpoint again and again until we get the desired result - recursion or loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a frontend application and a backend one. The frontend application asks the backend one to run a background job (e.g. `DELETE /api/v1/object/666`), the backend replies with `HTTP 202` and gives the link to the job (e.g. `https://.../api/v1/job/13`). Now the frontend application must periodically call this endpoint until the job is finished.

I implemented it as a recursive call, it looks like that:

```
  checkAsyncJob(
    jobId: string,
    interval: number = 2048,
    keepTrying: boolean = true,
    onFinish: Function
  ) {
    const jobResult
      = this.httpClient.get<Job>(this.urlComposer(JOB_BY_UID, jobId));
    jobResult.subscribe((job: Job) => {
      if (job.finished === null) {
        if (keepTrying) {
          // TODO: consider getting rid of recursion, it might should be a loop
          new Promise(
            resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval)
          ).then(
            () => this.checkAsyncJob(jobId, interval, keepTrying, onFinish)
          );
        }
      } else {
        onFinish();
      }
    });
  }
```

I would like to avoid recursion here, as it (I suppose) makes a browser consuming more and more RAM until the job is finished. Is there a way to reimplement it as a loop, considering that `httpClient.get()` returns a subscribable object and the main flow doesn't wait for its completion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJS has everything you need. Don't mix up and use imperative ifs together with promises, loops, recursions setTimeouts.

To resolve your problem take a look at this [article](https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-polling/)

Comment: Thank you, this article was exactly that piece what I needed for a better understanding of RxJS and its possibilities.

Comment: This answer provides barely more than a link to an external site. Please always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thank you, @fridoo, but I would like to admit that this link was enough for me to understand what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `retryWhen` of RxJS could solve your problem. It could be something like

```
this.httpClient.get<Job>(this.urlComposer(JOB_BY_UID, jobId))
  .pipe(
    map((job: Job) => {
      if (job.finished === null) {
        throw job; // throw as an error so can be catched by retryWhen
      }

      return job;
    }),
    retryWhen(errors => {
      errors.pipe(
        // timer is a RxJS function
        delayWhen(() => timer(interval)) // restart again after interval 
      )
    })
  )
  .subscribe(onFinish);
```

Reference:

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer

Hope it helps